# jenkins Active: active (exited), why not running status

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

`ubuntu 20.04`

`jenkins version: 2.282`

`java --version: openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19`

when I ran `sudo service jenkins start` and `sudo service jenkins status`, I got the following response, jenkins does not seem running.

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-03-05 17:11:47 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19834 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins jenkins[19834]: Correct java version found
Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins jenkins[19834]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins su[19873]: (to jenkins) root on none
Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins su[19873]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Mar 05 17:11:46 localjenkins su[19873]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Mar 05 17:11:47 localjenkins jenkins[19834]:    ...done.
Mar 05 17:11:47 localjenkins systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

however in my `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, I can see it says it is fully up and running?

```
*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

105896073c7842b9b71c68fed4e91918

This may also be found at: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

2021-03-05 17:53:29.447+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2021-03-05 17:53:29.458+0000 [id=23]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Update:
Finally I do see the site is up and running, but why isn't the status showing `Running` instead of `Exited`.
Anyone knows?
Thanks

Comment: What is not working? Have you chacked that is not listeneing on port 8080?

Comment: @S.Spieker, Oh I eventually realized it is running, and site can be displayed, but according to their official site, should I see `Active: active (running) since xxxx`, why isn't it show `Running`, but `exited` status.

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed the port number in /etc/defaults/jenkins from 8080 to 80 so it is showing

even I had the same issue, not able to access jenkins; now I have rechanged to 8080 now the site is working but still am seeing below but Jenkins is running and able to connect

oot@ip-10-0-0-13:~# service jenkins status
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-03-23 17:05:36 UTC; 16s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 964 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Succeeded.
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 jenkins[964]: Correct java version found
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 jenkins[964]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 su[997]: (to jenkins) root on none
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 su[997]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Mar 23 17:05:35 ip-10-0-0-13 su[997]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Mar 23 17:05:36 ip-10-0-0-13 jenkins[964]:    ...done.
Mar 23 17:05:36 ip-10-0-0-13 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time

My issue was resolved by changing the port number back but still showing Active (exited)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar message so posting it here in case it helps anyone. In my situation what was happening was that after I installed maven, along with it came Java 17 and it was set as the default Java version in the system. So even though there was Java 11 available, Jenkins was seeing 17, and it seems that it will not run with any version more recent than 11. Unfortunately it also doesn't report much about it in any of the logs I could find. So I was just seeing the "Active (exited)" status in systemctl, and no logging on either Jenkins or journalctl reported anything. I think a more clear message should be reported in this case.

Anyway the fix was to go into `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and set the `JENKINS_JAVA_CMD` variable there to point to your installed Java 11.